# iOS9 - Swift - Create app with simple build in browser

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

How could I setup with Xcode a simple app in Swift with tabs on the bottom which loads different websites with build in browser in the view? The tabs however, are less mandatory for now, at least the view should show the website when opened.
That is my code for the ViewController swift:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

However, when I open the simulator the view is blank white. Created a single view project in xcode.

Edit: Still having the issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should implement the WebView directly into code. Here's an example :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var webView: WKWebView?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let website = "https://www.apple.com"
    layoutWebBrowsingElements()
    loadURLRequest(website)

 }

 func loadURLRequest(address: String) {

    let siteURL = NSURL(string: address)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: siteURL!)
    webView?.loadRequest(request)

 }

 func layoutWebBrowsingElements() {

    // It is actually better to implement a WKWebView directly in code.

    let wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
    webView = wkWebView

    wkWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Auto-Layout Stuff

    self.view.addSubview(wkWebView)

    let webTopSpaceToContainer = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .TopMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
    let webBottomSpaceToContainer = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .BottomMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
    let webLeadingSpaceToContainer = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .LeadingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

    let webTrailingSpaceToContainer = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .TrailingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)

    let webViewConstaints = [webTopSpaceToContainer,webBottomSpaceToContainer,webLeadingSpaceToContainer,webTrailingSpaceToContainer]

    self.view.addConstraints(webViewConstaints)

 }

 }
```

This configuration supports auto-layout and "tap status bar to scroll to top"

You should also consider reading [WebKit's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#) , where you can get all properties and methods that can optimize your user's experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up toolbars in your storyboard and using those actions to trigger a URL in the app.

Comment: My main problem is to display actually the WebView aka load a page. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you typically would set this up:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(webView)

        let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.google.com/")
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
    }
}
```